# PHP while loop not returning anything on server

Tags: php, while-loop

```
if ($area == Null || $area == "Area of City") {
  $ment = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW water 
           AS SELECT postable.postid, description, dated, image, posterid, country, state, city, area, cat
             FROM postable 
           INNER JOIN ".$_GET['Cat']."
             ON postable.postid = ".$_GET['Cat'].".postid
           WHERE ".$_GET["Cat"].".cat = '".$_GET["what"]."'
             AND postable.country = '".$_GET["Country"]."'
             AND postable.state = '".$_GET["State"]."'
             AND postable.city = '".$_GET["City"]."'";
}

$ment = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW water
         AS SELECT postable.postid, description, dated, image, posterid, country, state, city, area, cat
           FROM postable, ".$_GET["Cat"]."
         WHERE (
           (postable.postid = ".$_GET["Cat"].".postid
           AND ".$_GET["Cat"].".cat = '".$_GET["what"]."'
           AND postable.country = '".$_GET["Country"]."'
           AND postable.state = '".$_GET["State"]."'
           AND postable.city = '".$_GET["City"]."'
           AND postable.area = '".$area."')
             OR
           (postable.postid = ".$_GET["Cat"].".postid
           AND ".$_GET["Cat"].".cat = '".$_GET["what"]."'
           AND postable.country = '".$_GET["Country"]."'
           AND postable.state = '".$_GET["State"]."'
           AND postable.city = '".$_GET["City"]."')
         )";
$tester = "SELECT * FROM water, userguy
           WHERE userguy.posterid = water.posterid";

if (!mysql_query($ment, $con)) {
  die('There are no posts matching your search, please enter another search in either another location or category, or both. ' );
}

if (!mysql_query($tester,$con)) {
  die('There are no posts matching your search, please enter another search in either another location or category, or both.');
}

$result = mysql_query($tester,$con);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($row == Null) {
  echo "<tr><td colspan'4'>There are no posts matching your search, please enter another search in either another location or category, or both.</td></tr>";}
  echo "<tr><td colspan='4' class='sult'>";
  echo "<div id='main'>".$row['description']."</div> ".$row['dated']." <a     href='mai.php?tofield=".$row['email']."'><b>".$row['email']."</b></a><b>&nbsp".$row['mobile']."</b>";
  if ($row['image'] != Null) {
    echo "<img src='upload/".$row['image']."' class='relt'/>";
  }
  echo "</td></tr>";
}

?>

<tr>
  <td colspan='4'>
     <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan='2' align='center'>
    <img src='first.jpg'/>
  </td>
  <td colspan='2' align='center'>
    <img src='second.jpg'/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan='2' align='center'>
    <img src='high.jpg'/>
  </td>
  <td colspan='2'></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Ok, now, this code works on my computer which I use to develop this my site, that is it returns the row from the database. However, when I put this code on my site it does not return anything, in fact, the table after the script does not even display at all. I would be grateful if I can get any help on this, it has been giving me sleepless nights for too long now...

Comment: do you have the same mysql with the same data and the same login-data (host, user, password) ? Do you get an error message with error_reporting on ?

Comment: Oh my, this code is in desperate need of some proper formatting and indentation. I would highly recommend taking some time to study and implement something like the Drupal coding standards (http://drupal.org/coding-standards), or simply do a Google search for "php coding standards" and see what else is out there. Your little grey cells (as well as those of the folks you're asking for help) will thank you. :)

Comment: @BrianShowalter Re-spaced code in the question for legibility... and immediately spotted several issue while doing so...

Comment: @invoq, my answer has been updated with stuff about logs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any immediate reason why your script shouldn't run, as halfer pointed out your message and error logs are the best place to look.

As an aside though: The first line in the while loop `if($row = Null)` will never be true (if it were, the while loop wouldn't be entered)
Consider

```
$n_rows = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $n_rows++;
    // Process row
}
if(!$n_rows) {
    // No rows message
}
```

(I realise this should be a comment not an answer but I don't have the points)

Comment: Welcome, and have some points :)

Comment: thanks guys, @halfer, the sql queries in the code I presented above works on my PC's server/database and mysql support is supported by my web-based php because another php file enters the data into the database, However, I would be grateful if u could direct me to where I can check my error logs and apache access logs. Another interesting thing is that the table after the php code does not display for some reason, I don't understand this, but it works on my PC and PHPmyadmin shows me the tables and the data in them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (see comments in code for changes):

```
<?php

  if ($area == Null || $area == "Area of City") {
    $ment = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW water 
             AS SELECT postable.postid, description, dated, image, posterid, country, state, city, area, cat
               FROM postable 
             INNER JOIN ".$_GET['Cat']."
               ON postable.postid = ".$_GET['Cat'].".postid
             WHERE ".$_GET["Cat"].".cat = '".$_GET["what"]."'
               AND postable.country = '".$_GET["Country"]."'
               AND postable.state = '".$_GET["State"]."'
               AND postable.city = '".$_GET["City"]."'";
  } else {
    // Pretty sure this should be in an else block
    // As it was, the query above would never be executed, because it would
    // always be overwritten by this one
    $ment = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW water
             AS SELECT postable.postid, description, dated, image, posterid, country, state, city, area, cat
               FROM postable, ".$_GET["Cat"]."
             WHERE (
               (postable.postid = ".$_GET["Cat"].".postid
               AND ".$_GET["Cat"].".cat = '".$_GET["what"]."'
               AND postable.country = '".$_GET["Country"]."'
               AND postable.state = '".$_GET["State"]."'
               AND postable.city = '".$_GET["City"]."'
               AND postable.area = '".$area."')
                 OR
               (postable.postid = ".$_GET["Cat"].".postid
               AND ".$_GET["Cat"].".cat = '".$_GET["what"]."'
               AND postable.country = '".$_GET["Country"]."'
               AND postable.state = '".$_GET["State"]."'
               AND postable.city = '".$_GET["City"]."')
             )";
  }

  $tester = "SELECT * FROM water, userguy
             WHERE userguy.posterid = water.posterid";

  /*
    Do you really not want the result of this query?
    Shouldn't you be catching the results in a variable?
    If not, consider adding a LIMIT 1 clause to the query, as the
    database will have to do more work to return a full result set
    you never use...
    Regardless of that, testing for !mysql_query doesn't tell you there
    were no results, it tells you whether the query itself failed. You
    test the number of results using mysql_num_rows() or a SELECT count() query
  */
  if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($ment, $con)) < 1) {
    die('There are no posts matching your search, please enter another search in either another location or category, or both. ' );
  }

  // Same goes for this.
  // However, since you definitely do want the results of this, why run it twice?
  $result = mysql_query($tester,$con);
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
    die('There are no posts matching your search, please enter another search in either another location or category, or both.');
  }

  // Use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array(), it's more efficient
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // if ($row == Null) {
    // Sorry, what? If the row is null??
    // It will never be null... if it were, the loop would break immediately
    // and never reach this point, plus mysql_fetch_* never returns null!
    //   echo "<tr><td colspan'4'>There are no posts matching your search, please enter another search in either another location or category, or both.</td></tr>";
    // }
    echo "<tr><td colspan='4' class='sult'>";
    echo "<div id='main'>".$row['description']."</div> ".$row['dated']." <a     href='mai.php?tofield=".$row['email']."'><b>".$row['email']."</b></a><b>&nbsp".$row['mobile']."</b>";
    if ($row['image'] != Null) {
      echo "<img src='upload/".$row['image']."' class='relt'/>";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
  }

?>

<tr>
  <td colspan='4'>
     <!--
       Really? You can't just use a CSS height?
     -->
     <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan='2' align='center'>
    <img src='first.jpg'/>
  </td>
  <td colspan='2' align='center'>
    <img src='second.jpg'/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan='2' align='center'>
    <img src='high.jpg'/>
  </td>
  <td colspan='2'></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Thorough answer, +1. Though I'd say the attributes should use double quotes rather than single ones - though of course they're a pain to specify in double-quoted strings... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I presume from the `$_GET` usage that you're running this in a browser, rather than from a console. It might be that your mysql extension is not loaded, or you don't have a valid connection to the database server.

- Firstly, check your error logs. These are usually kept in the same place as your Apache access logs*. This will give you an error message to work with.
- Next, run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in an otherwise empty page on your server, and see if mysql support is supported by your web-based PHP.
- Try running [mysql_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after db operations that might fail. This is also a good way to dig for errors.

Lastly bear in mind that your script has SQL injection security holes in it at present. Fix those probs before you go live with this :-).

Edit: * the location of your server logs depends on what OS you are using, and you have not specified this. This is quite easy to get from a search engine, however - if you are on Windows, then do a web search for "windows apache logs location". Easy ;-)

Edit 2: if SSH has been disabled, and you feel you need it, talk to your host. That is however a separate problem, and you don't need it to tackle the issue at hand. If your phpMyAdmin has problems, re-install it, or use the one provided by your host. (If you are using cPanel, this is included in your control panel.)

Comment: You need to use the back-tick symbol to let StackOverflow recognise code inline.

Comment: @halfer It is definitely necessary if you have to explain that you code shouldn't look the way it does, as you did above...

Comment: Okay guys, now it keeps giving me the folowing message when I use phpmyadmin; import.php: Missing parameter: import_type (FAQ 2.8)
import.php: Missing parameter: format (FAQ 2.8). Plus my SSh terminal has been disabled by my service provider just as my httpd config file, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again halfer, I've been in contact with my host and was told to send the error messages above. My web interface is plesk, so I guess it's on unix OS.

Comment: Great. Well, once you get phpMyAdmin back, the answers on this page should be sufficient to resolve your issue. Open a new question if you have a different problem :)

Comment: Thanks guys, the issue was that there was a    filter_var function for the $area variable just b4 the if statement, and my host's php version is lower than 5.2 which doesn't support the filter_var function. However, I had to check my error log file to see that. So thanks again guys especially Halfer...

Comment: No probs. Don't forget to assign points and/or tick as you see fit :).